# Plugin De/Activation Not Firing On MultiSite install

Tags: plugins, multisite, activation, user-registration

I have a very rudimentary plugin in development, but at the point of needing to enable the `register_activation_hook()` and `register_deactivation_hook()` I have stalled. I am getting zero output from `error_log('it ran')` debugging statements.

This plugin is going to be run on a multisite install (so I am developing it on a multisite install). I need to create a custom table for the business logic of the work, but until I can get this hook happy I am getting nowhere.

Interestingly, if I **Network Activate** this same plugin, the site locks me out with a "*You do not have permission to access this page.*" message.  I have to clear the `wp_sitemeta` option: `active_network_plugins` to get back on the site again.

I'm praying someone hears a bell ringing with this description and ca straighten me out quickly.

Comment: If you would post the code it would be possible for us to evaluate this better, and to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I was attempting to use register_activation_hook too late in the loading cycle.Moving it outside my class init function to the global scope made it behave as expected.

Comment: Please use Syntax highlighting and show your _complete_ solution instead of an explanation of it. Thanks.